# Hosting MVC application inside a subdomain

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, hosting, subdomain, iis-8

I have an existing website currently hosted on IIS 7 and is configured to run on .NET v2. The setup in the IIS looks like below:

```
Sites
 * mywebsite 
   - services
```

where

- mywebsite is .NET 2 asp.net website, hosted inside AppPool named "app", and .NET version 2
- services is a subdomain again asp.net website, with AppPool named "services" .NET version 2

I would like to add .NET 4 mvc application as one more subdomain say - "web" under the "mywebsite" website, so my structure would look like:

```
Sites
 * mywebsite 
   - web <- new .net mvc 4 website, new AppPool named "web" .NET 4 Integrated
   - services
```

First query:
1. Is it possible to have subdomain with different .NET version?

I tried to do the above setup, but I get an error message, when I browse though to `http://mywebsite/web`

```
There is a duplicate 'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler' section defined
```

Any ideas, what am I missing? please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should disable web.config inheritance. You should use this code in the mywebsite web.config: